# How to set credentials in FirebaseCloudMessagingService

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-cloud-messaging

I used to use dotnet package `FirebaseAdmin` and initialize with:

```cs
fbm = FirebaseMessaging.GetMessaging(
    FirebaseApp.Create(
        new AppOptions()
        {
            Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("path/to/serviceAccount.json")
        }
    )
);
```

But I recieved a message saying the bulk send endpoint I was using is being deprecated and I should update to the http v1 api which is in package `Google.Apis.FirebaseCloudMessaging.v1`. Afai can tell I should initialize a `FirebaseCloudMessagingService` but it is not clear to me how/where to pass in my service account credentials like I used to. The docs dont seem to help since most of them still refer to the older firebase admin sdk package.